# JBossXBException

Tags: java, maven-2, jboss, ejb, maven-ear-plugin

I have an ear file that is generated through Maven EAR plugin. The ear file has only one module which is the ejb module. I am able to deploy it to JBoss 4.2.1-GA inside Eclipse but when I tried running it an exception is encountered during startup. I've tried searching for a solution for two days now but unsuccessful.

The exception I encountered was

```
org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: Premature end of file. @ *unknown*[-1,-1]
```

The stack trace is here: [stack trace](http://pastebin.com/nZmCxdMj)

It might be worth noting that this is an existing project that I am trying to "mavenize" and was working properly before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds as if within the jar file you try to deploy, `osf-feed-ejbs.jar` the deployment descriptor (ejb-jar.xml probably) is missing.

If it is within the META-INF folder and you are on Windows, make sure that `META-INF` is all caps!

You don't need `ejb-jar.xml` for EJB3 deployments. But if you have one, it needs to be wellformed at least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Heiko. Do I need to include ejb-jar.xml if I am using EJB 3? I'll try to include it though and let you know what happens.

Comment: I checked the generated jar by maven ejb plugin and it generates an empty ejb-jar.xml which I think might be the cause of the parse exception. I'm searching a way for the plugin not to generate ejb-jar.xml with the jar.

Comment: I finally saw that there is an ejb-jar.xml in the resources directory. Thanks for your time Heiko and sorry if the cause is somewhat stupid, this is an existing codebase that I am trying to mavenize.